# Prose.io content management workflow explained

Tags: jekyll, prose

I'm looking into prose.io and I would like to find out more about the content management work flow.

Do prose.io content contributors get access via prose.io to the master repository on GitHub or do they work on a branch or even on a fork?

I'm wondering how much can go wrong and how messy the master repo gets when everyone has access?

Is there an option to combine pull requests with prose?

Answer (score 0):

Using prose for my personal blog and its the master repo prose gets access to.

However there is something you can do. In Jekyll `_config.yml` you can set prose parameter option for `rooturl: "DIRECTORY NAME"` what this does is limits the prose access to directory.  In my case there is directory called `_posts` and prose cannot edit anything outside of it. There is also `ignore` option that basically makes folders invisible on prose. I

Here is my prose config for use as an example. Here I use both root and ignore options.

```
prose:
  rooturl: '_posts'
  media: 'img'
  ignore:
    - 404.html
    - LICENSE
    - feed.xml
    - _config.yml
    - /_layouts
    - /_includes
    - /css
    - /img
    - /js
  metadata:
    _posts:
      - name: "layout"
        field:
          element: "hidden"
          value: "post"
      - name: "title"
        field:
          element: "text"
          label: "Post title"
          placeholder: "Title"
          alterable: true
      - name: "subtitle"
        field:
          element: "textarea"
          label: "Subtitle"
          placeholder: "A description of your post."
          alterable: true
      - name: "date"
        field:
          element: "text"
          label: "Date"
          help: "Enter date of post."
          placeholder: "yyyy-mm-dd"
          alterable: true
      - name: "published"
        field:
          element: "checkbox"
          label: "Publish"
          help: "Check to publish post, uncheck to hide."
```

More on the options here >

https://github.com/prose/prose/wiki/Prose-Configuration

Answer (score 0):

Prose doesn't necessarily commit to `master`, rather it commits to your default branch. That is usually `master`, but you can [change it](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-the-default-branch/). For instance, if you're using GitHub Pages your default branch would be `gh-pages`.

In our workflow, we're now trying to separate the branch that contributors edit on from the version we use for production. We leave the default as `master` (for simplicity), but keep our production version in a separate branch (e.g. `production`). Project owners then carefully merge or cherry pick from `master` into `production`.

Prose may soon allow you to [change the branch it commits to](https://github.com/prose/prose/issues/876) from the GitHub default branch, at which point we'll revisit our workflow.